# How to build a StreamBuilder inside SliverList

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently trying to create a sliverlist that gets a list of user UID's from firebase then uses the streambuilder to find the information for each user. The problem is that is creates a bunch of sliverlists with a streambuilder listview inside so I have a bunch of items that are part of their own individual lists. **How can I make this more efficiently to only build one sliverlist with all the item?**

```
return SliverList(
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (context, index) {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: userSearch(context, snapshot.data['members'][index]),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return userWidget(
                context,
                snapshot.data[index],
              );
            },
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                const Divider(),
          );
        },
      );
    },
    childCount: snapshot.data['members'].length,
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html) as the `ScrollPhysics` for the inner `ListView`.

It makes the `ListView` not scroll which means only the `SliverList` can scroll the items.

```dart
return ListView.separated(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Add this line
  ...
);
```